# Instance Variable thought to be missing method

Tags: java

so my goal is to create a method for both the pagesRead() instance variable and the typeHomework instance variable, but when i try this, I get an error saying that they are missing method or to declare abstract. If someone could help me figure this out or send me to another question similar that would be wonderful, thank you.

```
public abstract class homework {
    public int pagesRead();
    public String typeHomework();
    public abstract void createAssignment(int p) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: take off the braces () from pagesRead and typeHomework. Variables do not have braces.

Comment: Unrelated, but classes should be named using Pascal case, so `Homework` instead of `homework`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public abstract class homework
{
   public abstract int pagesRead();//abstract
   public abstract String typeHomework();//abstract
   public abstract void createAssignment(int p);//since it is an abstract you can't create a body
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for should be:

```
public abstract class homework {
    abstract int pagesRead();

    abstract String typeHomework();

    public void createAssignment(int p) {
        //
    }
}
```

You inverted everything.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First an **abstract** method cannot have implementation.

Your code should be

```
public abstract class homework {
    public abstract int pagesRead();
    public  abstract String typeHomework();
    public  void createAssignment(int p){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to create class members? That is pagesRead and typeHomework should be elements of class Homework and not methods? If so, then following is the proper way

```
    public class Homework{ 
        public int pagesRead;
        public String typeHomework;
        public void createAssignment(int p)
              { return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have declared in the abstract class is reverse . 
    1) Declared non abstract methods 
    2) given implementation for abstract methods

```
You should 
1) Declared abstract methods 
2) given implementation for non abstract methods
```